# Percona on 2nd node will not start

Tags: networking, mysql, vagrant, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

I have setup two Vagrant VMs to simulate Percona XtraDB Cluster for our development needs. The first VM comes online just fine, and everything works. However, when I try to start Percona on the 2nd VM we get errors when requesting state transfer.

This is the error we get on **db1**:

```
rsync: failed to connect to 10.0.2.15: Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(124) [sender=3.0.6]
rsync returned code 10:
130416 17:19:07 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read from: wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'donor' --address '10.0.2.15:4444/rsync_sst' --auth '(null)' --socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/data/' --defaults-file '/etc/my.cnf' --gtid '684d0eda-a6e5-11e2-0800-75b8bb33fbfb:3'
130416 17:19:07 [Note] WSREP: Provider resumed.
130416 17:19:07 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'donor' --address '10.0.2.15:4444/rsync_sst' --auth '(null)' --socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/data/' --defaults-file '/etc/my.cnf' --gtid '684d0eda-a6e5-11e2-0800-75b8bb33fbfb:3': 255 (Unknown error 255)
130416 17:19:07 [Warning] WSREP: 1 (db1.ellis.dev.liquidcompass.net): State transfer to 0 (db2.ellis.dev.liquidcompass.net) failed: -1 (Operation not permitted)
```

What I'm finding interesting is that it's trying to connect to 10.0.2.15, when the IP of **db2** is 192.168.160.211. Running `ifconfig` on **db1** show the following network configuration:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:42:B3:4F
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe42:b34f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:668 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:55869 (54.5 KiB)  TX bytes:63186 (61.7 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:90:38:2A
          inet addr:192.168.160.80  Bcast:192.168.160.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe90:382a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2863 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:286053 (279.3 KiB)  TX bytes:18650 (18.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:200 (200.0 b)  TX bytes:200 (200.0 b)
```

So that is telling me that Percona is trying to use `eth0` when rsyncing. Shouldn't it be using `eth1`?

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Can you add the routing tables for both **db1** and **db2**, the output of ifconfig for **db2** and clarify which machine **db1** is supposed to rsync with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Percona by default uses eth0 unless overridden.

It uses the following command to work out the ip address it should communicate on:

```
/sbin/ifconfig | grep -E '^[[:space:]]+inet addr:' | grep -m1 -v 'inet addr:127' | sed 's/:/ /' | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Which results in 10.0.2.15.

The wsrep_node_address variable can be set which tells it to use an alternate ip:

```
wsrep_node_address=192.168.160.80:4567
```

We had the same problem and it fixed it for us.

James

Comment: Thank you! I posted this on my old account and just saw the answer. Now I have replication working in my dev environment.